# Is it possible to use boost::bind to effectively concatenate functions?

Tags: c++, boost, callback, bind, functor

Assume that I have a boost::function of with an arbitrary signature called type `CallbackType`.

- *Is it possible to use `boost::bind` to compose a function that takes the same arguments as the CallbackType but calls the two functors in succession?*

I'm open to any potential solution, but here's a...

...Hypothetical example using some `magic` template:

```
Template<typename CallbackType>
class MyClass
{
    public:
        CallbackType doBoth;

        MyClass( CallbackType callback )
        {
            doBoth = bind( magic<CallbackType>, 
                             protect( bind(&MyClass::alert, this) ),   
                               protect( callback )                    );
        }

        void alert()
        {
            cout << "It has been called\n";
        }
};

void doIt( int a, int b, int c)
{
    cout << "Doing it!" << a << b << c << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    typedef boost::function<void (int, int, int)> CallbackType;

    MyClass<CallbackType> object( boost::bind(doIt) );

    object.doBoth();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is `magic` supposed to be implemented in terms of `bind`? What is the role of `bind` supposed to be? Certainly you're not actually binding anything to the callback.

Comment: `magic` would perhaps be some template that automatically created a functor that took two functors as arguments + all of the arguments of `CallbackType`... but this is just meant to illustrate my goal, not necessarily offer a realistic solution. I'm open to drastically different suggestions.

Comment: Are you trying to compose a `void (void)` with `void (int, int, int)`? Or was that just a typo?

Comment: No, that is correct... just another complication of the problem. The template has no way of knowing ahead of time what the sig would be so could not make `alert` match it.

Comment: Could you state clearly what is the composition you want to achieve with a concrete and simple example (without bind)? Take in account that function composition has a sense when the result of a function is the input of the other.

Comment: I'm more trying to concatenate than compose, though concatenation can be thought of as a weird special case of composition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Boost already provides a way to create a sequence of bound functions. Use [Lambda's comma operator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/lambda/le_in_details.html#lambda.comma_operator).

```
using namespace boost::lambda;
MyClass mc;
CallbackType object = (bind(&MyClass::alert, mc), bind(doIt, _1, _2, _3));
object(1, 2, 3);
```

That will create a new functor, `object`. When you invoke that functor with three arguments, it will in turn call `mc.alert()` before passing those arguments to `doIt`. The parentheses are important.

For my example above to work, you'd need `alert` to be a `const` function. If it needs to be non-const, then either pass a *pointer* to `mc`, or wrap it with [`boost::ref(mc)`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/ref.html). And you'll need to use Boost.Lambda's `bind` rather than Boost.Bind's; the latter isn't compatible with Lambda's function-combining operators (comma, in particular).

Answer (score 1):

```
template< class Callback >
struct pre_caller {
    Callback c;

    pre_caller( Callback in_c ) : c( in_c ) {}

    void alert() {} // or an instance of a functor

    operator()
    { alert(); c(); }

    template< class T1 >
    operator( T1 a ) // not sure if/what qualification to add to a
    { alert(); c( a ); } // or whether to attempt to obtain from
                         // function_traits<Callback>?
    template< class T1, class T2 >
    operator( T1 a, T2 b )
    { alert(); c( a, b ); }

    template< class T1, class T2, class T3 >
    operator( T1 a, T2 b, T3 c )
    { alert(); c( a, b, c ); }

    // ad nauseam... and I mean nausea, maybe read up on Boost Preprocessor.
};
```

Boost Bind uses a lot of preprocessor hacking for its variadic voodoo, and unfortunately I don't think it provides a pattern or tools for head-patching which is essentially what this is.

Comment: It seems like there should be an easier way, and perhaps my my straw man example goes in the complete wrong direction.  Starting a bounty, but this may end up marked as the answer.